# rails and rake commands freeze/hang

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I've recently updated an old application to from 3.2.13 to 4.2.10. I've got the application running in development mode but any rake or rails commands I try to run just hang/freeze. The terminal window will hang for a second and then nothing, I'm unable to even stop the process with ctrl-c. I've read a lot about running 'spring stop' to fix this but I don't have spring installed on this app.

Running the commands with --trace aren't particularly helpful.
`rails generate model Foo --trace` gives me nothing and `rake db:migrate --trace` gives me:
`** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate`
before freezing. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What's your database configuration?  Is the DB server taking a loooong time to respond? What if you wait a few mins? Will the rake task finally crash with _some_ message? I don't think it'll hang indefinitely.

Comment: Ah thank you, this has got me a little closer. I had the wrong password set for my database on the development environment, so rake db:migrate is working now.

Still no luck with generating models/migrations though. I'm not sure how long it takes to crash, I've had one terminal window open for 30 minutes so far with it just hanging.

Comment: Okay so the command finally finished running and it did create the migration eventually. On a hunch though I tried 
RAILS_ENV=production rails g migration Foo
And it ran instantly with no problems so it looks like the issue is with the development environment. I've took this app over from another developer so don't know where to even start looking for the cause of the slowdown.

Comment: Does it try to connect to DB server on that other developer's machine, maybe? :)

Comment: No, everything is pointed at my local database now. I've tried pasting production.rb environment into the the development.rb hoping it would just be a quick configuration to fix the issue but that hasn't made any difference. I suppose I need to grep the application to find out if the development environment is doing anything weird.

Comment: Yep, good luck there.